# Having an issue where the on-screen stick component on unity doesnt get dragged anymore

Tags: unity-game-engine, joystick

I was working on a game of mine, and the stick was working initially, but on the latest compile, the stick doesn't move anymore, I cant say it it isn't getting clicked or there is an issue with the component, I'm fairly new to unity, please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself, I had accidentally Changed the action asset in the event system to a non default one that didn't have the button interactions.